# MongoDB throws "Error: Connection was destroyed by application" during insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I check if a specific key value pair exists and insert if they don't exist. For some strange reason MongoDB throws an error during insert. Any help would much appreciated.

Update #2: Added entire function.

```
{
    var connectURL  = "mongodb://something";
    var mycollection= "something2";
    var db;
    var col;

    async.series([
      // Connect to DB
      function(callback) {
              MongoClient.connect(connectURL,function(error, db2) {
                      if (error) {console.log("db connect error" + error);callback(error,"db connect error"); return;} 
                      db = db2;
                      callback(null,"connect success");
              });
      },
      function(callback) {
              col = db.collection(mycollection);
          callback(null,"collection success");
      },
      function(callback) {
              //console.log ("insert begin ...");                     
              var i = 1;
              async.whilst(
                function() { return i <= count },
                function(callback) {
                    var mydocument = rows.shift();      
                    col.findOne({ "sha" : mydocument.sha}, function(err, doc) {
                      console.log ("checked ....",  mydocument.sha);  
                      if(doc != null) {
                        console.log ("Exist :" + mydocument.sha);
                      } else {
                        console.log ("Inserting : " + mydocument.sha);    
                        col.insert(mydocument,function(error,result) {
                         if (error) {
                         console.log("insert error:" + error);
                         callback(error);
                         return;
                         }
                         i++;
                        console.log ("inserted ...");
                       }); //end insert   
                    } //end else
             i++;
             });//end findOne
            callback(null); 
        },
                function(error) {
                  callback(error,"insert sucess")
                }
              ); //end async.whilst
      },
      function (callback){
              //console.log ("###########close db");
              db.close();
              console.log("## end insert: "+ moment().format());
              callback(null,"connection closed");
      }
     ], function(error, results) {
                    if (error) { console.log("error"); }
                            //console.log(results);
            });     
}
```

Output

```
checked .... 078d40cc537de96310e945a50a60b0084e21d2e1
Inserting : 078d40cc537de96310e945a50a60b0084e21d2e1
insert error:Error: Connection was destroyed by application

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha' of undefined
```

Comment: `col` is clearly defined outside of this function and it is unclear  where this function is being called from in terms of scope and that there is not in fact a disconnect being called anywhere in code. This should indeed be called from within whatever is grabbing the `col` object, and also with none of those other actions mentioned occurring anywhere.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just updated the code with global variables. ````col```` is one of the global variables.

Comment: You need to post more code. Include where `col` and `row` are used.

Comment: We need to see this in context. Global variables are not the magic pill you likely think they are. The code needs to be closed within callbacks in some way or another, and it likely is not.

Comment: I just updated the post with entire function. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Denote *cb1* as the callback of `col.findOne`, and *cb2* as the callback of `col.insert`.

*cb1* returns once it issues `col.insert` without waiting *cb2* to finish. Since *cb1* also increment **i** and your testing function provided to `async.whilst` would then evaluate to be false, which cause the `async.whilst` thought it has finished all iterations.
So `async.series` moves on to the next task, which then issues `db.close`. Therefore the database connection may be closed before the remaining insertion commands are finished.

By the way, it seems your code snippet would jam the database by repeatedly issue `col.findOne`. Your **i** increases in either *cb1* or *cb2*, but the `async.whilst` may repeatedly do the testing and execution many many times before each time **i** can be incremented. Perhaps you could use `setTimeout(callback,...)` instead of calling the callback immediately.